search for the next highest value mongodb
I am currently working on a price search engine with NodeJS and Mongoose and have a question about the implementation of a price matrix.
Each product has an icon, a type symbol, a width, a height and a price. For example, I have a product with the symbol: T5, type symbol: F, width: 900, height: 210 and price: 322.
The price matrix contains consecutive values as follows:

Width: 1000, Height: 210, Price: 345
Width: 1200, height: 210, price: 398
Width: 1400, Height: 210, Price: 449

My problem is that when searching for the next price value, my code selects the next but one value if the value searched for is between two existing values. For example, for a width of 1160, the value for 1400 is selected directly instead of 1200.
Here is my code:
const symbol = findProfil.symbol;
const typsymbol = product.symbol;

const findPrice = await profilSubPriceModel.aggregate([
    {
        $match: {
            symbol: symbol,
            typSymbol: typsymbol
        }
    },
    {
        $addFields: {
            wide: { $toInt: "$wide" }, // Konvertieren von wide von String zu Int
            height: { $toInt: "$height" } // Konvertieren von height von String zu Int
        }
    },
    {
        $addFields: {
            wideDiff: { $abs: { $subtract: ["$wide", inputWidth + 65]}},
            heightDiff: { $abs: {$subtract: ["$height", inputHeight + 45]}}
        }
    },
    {
        $addFields: {
            validWidth: { $ceil: { $divide: [{ $toInt: "$wide" }, 100] } },
            validHeight: { $ceil: { $divide: [{ $toInt: "$height" }, 100] } }
        }
    },
    {
        $addFields: {
            totalDiff: { $add: ["$wideDiff", "$heightDiff"] }
        }
    },
    {
        $sort: { totalDiff: 1 }
    },
    {
        $limit: 3
    }
]);

How can I change my code so that the correct next value in the matrix is selected instead of the next but one value?
I keep getting the same value.
if (findPrice.length === 0) {
            const findLargerPrice = await profilSubPriceModel.aggregate([
                {
                    $match: {
                        symbol: symbol,
                        typSymbol: typsymbol
                    }
                },
                {
                    $addFields: {
                        wide: { $toInt: "$wide" },
                        height: { $toInt: "$height" }
                    }
                },
                {
                    $addFields: {
                        wideDiff: { $subtract: ["$wide", inputWidth] },
                        heightDiff: { $subtract: ["$height", inputHeight] }
                    }
                },
                {
                    $match: {
                        wideDiff: { $gte: 0 },
                        heightDiff: { $gte: 0 }
                    }
                },
                {
                    $addFields: {
                        totalDiff: { $add: ["$wideDiff", "$heightDiff"] }
                    }
                },
                {
                    $sort: { totalDiff: 1 }
                },
                {
                    $limit: 3
                }
            ]);

            if (findLargerPrice.length > 0) {
                findPrice.push(...findLargerPrice);
            }
        }


I see couple of issues in your searching logic as follows:

validWidth and validHeight  fields were not contributing to finding the closest match then why did you added that.

The totalDiff calculation is also incorrect, this calculation is not focusing on the actual closest match due to additional transformations on widths and heights.

Missing filtering of Negative differences.

Didn't understood why you're using a limit of 3 since using $limit: 3 instead of $limit: 1 allowed multiple results to be included potentially including non-closest values.


Changes that I have made on your code:

Try removing unnecessary fields i.e validWidth and validHeight (Remove this part of the code below)

{
    $addFields: {
        validWidth: { $ceil: { $divide: [{ $toInt: "$wide" }, 100] } },
        validHeight: { $ceil: { $divide: [{ $toInt: "$height" }, 100] } }
    }
}


Include a $match stage to filter out negative differences by ensuring wideDiff and heightDiff are greater than or equal to 0.

{
    $match: {
        wideDiff: { $gte: 0 },
        heightDiff: { $gte: 0 }
    }
}


Changed $limit to 1 in both the main query and the fallback query.

{
    $limit: 1
}

Here is the complete updated code with above changes do give it a try and if this works/not work let me know.
const symbol = findProfil.symbol;
const typsymbol = product.symbol;

const findPrice = await profilSubPriceModel.aggregate([
    {
        $match: {
            symbol: symbol,
            typSymbol: typsymbol
        }
    },
    {
        $addFields: {
            wide: { $toInt: "$wide" },
            height: { $toInt: "$height" }
        }
    },
    {
        $addFields: {
            wideDiff: { $subtract: ["$wide", inputWidth] },
            heightDiff: { $subtract: ["$height", inputHeight] }
        }
    },
    {
        $match: {
            wideDiff: { $gte: 0 },
            heightDiff: { $gte: 0 }
        }
    },
    {
        $addFields: {
            totalDiff: { $add: ["$wideDiff", "$heightDiff"] }
        }
    },
    {
        $sort: { totalDiff: 1 }
    },
    {
        $limit: 1
    }
]);

if (findPrice.length === 0) {
    const findLargerPrice = await profilSubPriceModel.aggregate([
        {
            $match: {
                symbol: symbol,
                typSymbol: typsymbol
            }
        },
        {
            $addFields: {
                wide: { $toInt: "$wide" },
                height: { $toInt: "$height" }
            }
        },
        {
            $addFields: {
                wideDiff: { $subtract: ["$wide", inputWidth] },
                heightDiff: { $subtract: ["$height", inputHeight] }
            }
        },
        {
            $match: {
                wideDiff: { $gte: 0 },
                heightDiff: { $gte: 0 }
            }
        },
        {
            $addFields: {
                totalDiff: { $add: ["$wideDiff", "$heightDiff"] }
            }
        },
        {
            $sort: { totalDiff: 1 }
        },
        {
            $limit: 1
        }
    ]);

    if (findLargerPrice.length > 0) {
        findPrice.push(...findLargerPrice);
    }
}


This looks like a ranking problem. You can use $setWindowFields to compute the rank for totalDiff and select rank <= 3 at the end
db.collection.aggregate([
  {
    $match: {
      symbol: "T5",
      typSymbol: "F"
    }
  },
  {
    "$set": {
      wideDiff: {
        $abs: {
          $subtract: [
            "$width",
            1160
          ]
        }
      },
      heightDiff: {
        $abs: {
          $subtract: [
            "$height",
            210
          ]
        }
      }
    }
  },
  {
    "$set": {
      totalDiff: {
        $add: [
          "$wideDiff",
          "$heightDiff"
        ]
      }
    }
  },
  {
    "$setWindowFields": {
      "sortBy": {
        "totalDiff": 1
      },
      "output": {
        "rank": {
          $rank: {}
        }
      }
    }
  },
  {
    "$match": {
      rank: {
        $lte: 3
      }
    }
  }
])

Mongo Playground
